# Route params require arguments to be passed to the action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

I have the following code in my routes.rb file -

```
post "/webhooks/process/:webhook_source", controller: :webhooks, action: :process
```

What is expected is that it would pass the `webhook_source` as a param in the action.

Here is the action -

```
  def process(webhook_source)
    puts "========="
    puts webhook_source
    puts "========="
    case params[:webhook_source]
    when 'razorpay'
      process_razorpay(params)
    end
    head :ok
  end
```

If I don't have the argument `webhook_source`, I get the error -

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/T3eu2srT) is the full stack track for reference as well.

And the puts of `webhook_source` just returns `process`.

I'm unsure of how to get rid of the argument which I think is redundant.

Comment: Can you include also a stack trace of the error? There should really be no need for the `webhook_source`  parameter.

Comment: @edariedl - here's the stack trace - https://pastebin.com/T3eu2srT

Comment: This is weird, it should work without it. Could you share complete code of your controller please?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the syntax error as the methods in the class that inherit ActionController can't have method params of thier own. Your `process` method should be

```rb
def process 
    puts "========="
    puts params[:webhook_source]
    puts "========="
    case params[:webhook_source]
    when 'razorpay'
      process_razorpay(params)
    end
    head :ok
 end
```

**Update:**

The problem lies in the name of the method. `process` is a keyword used by [AbstractController#Base](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb#L127). Defining the method with different name that is not a keyword would solve the trouble.

Comment: I get the error only when I have the code without the params.. I have to include the params for it to go away..

Comment: May be you should use a different name to the method. `process` could be a keyword in `rails`

Comment: @sureshprasanna70 good catch. You are correct `process` is method defined by rails https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb#L127 and it got overridden by action method in the controller.